# jquery process a form which is inside a loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I process a form if the fields are inside a loop, which means that the field value is generated till the loop counts. My codes are below:

jQuery

```
$('.action').click(function() {
  var form = document.action;
  var dataString = $(form).serialize();
  var btnValue = $(".action").html();
  var btnElement = $(".action");
  var formType = $(".formType").val();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: $(form).attr("action"),
    data: dataString,
    cache: true,
    beforeSend: function(){
      $('.message').hide();
      btnElement.html('Please wait...');
    },
    success: function(data){
      $('.message').html(data).fadeIn();
      btnElement.html(btnValue);
      $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
      if(formType == 'login'){
        if($('.message').find('#responseBox').hasClass('success')){
          setTimeout(function(){
            window.location.replace("dashboard.php");
          }, 2000);
        }
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

HTML

```
<form method="post" action="processes/memberships.php">
  <select name="package">
    {foreach $upgVal[$mb.mb_id] as $uv}
      <option value="{$uv.upval_id}">{$uv.upval_months} {if $uv.upval_months > 1}months{else}month{/if} for {$currencySymbol}{$uv.upval_amount}</option>
    {/foreach}
  </select>
  <br><br>
  <button type="submit" class="action btn-main"><span>Upgrade</span></button>
</form>
```

I am trying to send the select data to another page. I can make this work if I wrote a new function without `$(form).serialize();` method by `var dataString = { package: $(this).parent().find(".package").val() };`. However, I don't want to create more JS functions for a single task. I want to process this data with the same jQuery code above. How can I do that?

Comment: Only one of those generated options will be selected when you submit the form. No issue

Comment: Remember the FORM is not inside a loop, just the options in your dropdown are created in a loop

Comment: `var form = document.action;` looks weird to me... For a start, try `var form = $(this).closest("form")` -- Then `var dataString = $(form).serialize();` would be `var dataString = form.serialize();`

Answer (score 0):

Form data can be processed using the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData).